# Where to put BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT for boost::serialization?

Tags: c++, boost-serialization

I'm trying to serialize a pointer to a polymorphic class `Shape`. So I need to use the [`BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT` macro](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html) to define a GUID for each subclass. The problem: where to put it?

Let me show a minimal test case first:

**shapes.hpp**

```
#include <boost/serialization/access.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/base_object.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/export.hpp>

class Shape {
    friend class boost::serialization::access;

    template<typename Archive>
    void serialize(Archive &ar, unsigned int const version) {
        // nothing to do
    }

    public:
        virtual ~Shape() { }
};

class Rect : public Shape {
    friend class boost::serialization::access;

    template<typename Archive>
    void serialize(Archive &ar, unsigned int const version) {
        ar & boost::serialization::base_object<Shape>(*this);
    }

    public:
        virtual ~Rect() { }
};

#ifdef EXPORT_IN_HEADER
    BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT(Rect)
#endif
```

**export.cpp**

```
#include <boost/serialization/export.hpp>
#include "shapes.hpp"

#ifdef EXPORT_IN_OBJECT
    BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT(Rect)
#endif
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/export.hpp>
#include "shapes.hpp"

#ifdef EXPORT_IN_MAIN
    BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT(Rect)
#endif

int main() {
    Shape *shape = new Rect();
    boost::archive::text_oarchive ar(std::cout);
    ar << shape;
}
```

On gcc, I compile these with

```
g++ -omain main.cpp export.cpp -Wl,-Bstatic -lboost_serialization-mt -Wl,-Bdynamic -DEXPORT_IN_XXX
```

Here, `export.cpp` may look a bit silly. In my actual situation, it contains an enclosing class that uses the PIMPL idiom, and tries to serialize its (polymorphic) `Shape` implementation. The important point is: the `BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT` could be in a *different* object file than the code that invokes the serialization.

So here's the problem: where to use `BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT`? I have three options, which can be enabled using the `EXPORT_IN_XXX` macros.

1. `EXPORT_IN_MAIN` works, but is not what I want. The code invoking the serialization should not need to know about the implementation details of the PIMPL class.
2. `EXPORT_IN_OBJECT` compiles, but does not work: it results in a `boost::archive::archive_exception` with the message `unregistered void cast`. According to the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/serialization/doc/serialization.html#runtimecasting), this should be solved by serializing base classes using `boost::serialization::base_object`, like I did, but it doesn't help.
3. `EXPORT_IN_HEADER` does not even compile. The macro `BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT` expands to a template specialization (which we'd like to be in the header file), but also to the definitiof of a static member therein. So I get a linker error about a `multiple definition of 'boost::archive::detail::init_guid<Rect>::guid_initializer'`.

If it matters, I'm using g++ 4.4.3 and Boost 1.40.

Comment: Have you solved this problem? I have encountered this problem myself, either getting an unregistered class exception at run time or `boost::archive::detail::init_guid<SomeClass>::guid_initializer` errors at compile time.
I am pretty stumped, so if you've figured it out since asking this question, I'd really appreciate if you shared!! Thanks!

Comment: @bguiz: Not really solved it, no. See my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up putting all the serialization code in a header `s11n.h` that is included from the CPP file that invokes the serialization. Essentially, the `EXPORT_IN_MAIN` scenario I sketched above, but with the `BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT` macro invocations in a different file.

This only works as long as only one compilation unit includes `s11n.h`, of course, so although it works for now, it's no real solution...

Comment: Alas, this didn't work for me - what I wound up doing was to use `Archive::register_type(static_cast<ClassName*>(NULL))` within the serialize method of the central class being serilaized.
This worked for me, h/w I don't think it is the same scenario you encountered~

Comment: @bguiz: Well, that would be an argument *against* use of the abbreviation, I guess... ;) But I'm the only one maintaining this code, so it's not a problem for me. Saves loads of typing.

Answer (score 10):

[Exporting Class Serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/serialization/doc/special.html#export) of the Boost.Serialization docs (1.44.0) states the following:

---

> `BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT` in the same
>   source module that includes any of the
>   archive class headers will instantiate
>   code [...]
>
> Note that the implemenation of this
>   functionality requires that the
>   `BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT` macro appear
>   after and the inclusion of any archive
>   class headers for which code is to be
>   instantiated. So, code that uses
>   `BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT` will look like
>   the following:

```
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
... // other archives

#include "a.hpp" // header declaration for class a
BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT(a)
... // other class headers and exports
```

> [...] Including `BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT` in
>   the "a.hpp" header itself as one would
>   do with other serialization traits
>   will make it difficult or impossible
>   to follow the rule above regarding
>   inclusion of archive headers before
>   `BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT` is invoked. This
>   can best be addressed by using
>   `BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_KEY` in the header
>   declarations and `BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_IMPLEMENT` in the
>   class definition file.

---

Comment: I have put the BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_KEY in my header and the BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_IMPLEMENT in my implementation file. I build a library out of those, and then when I try to serialize the object in an executable that links to the library the serializer doesn't know about the type. See this example: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/28926778#28926778

Comment: @DavidDoria - sorry, can't help you there. Long time since doing anything with Boost.Ser

Answer (score 2):

You can use EXPORT_IN_OBJECT but the file that contains BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT must also include all the archive hpp files that plan to use.

This is because the BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT macro registers the derived type information which each archive it thinks you will use (implicitly determined based upon which archives you have included.)

In your example, use EXPORT_IN_OBJECT but also add #include 
to export.cpp.

In our code, we created archives.hpp that contains the archives we use and include it where ever we need to use BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT.  (That way we have a single official list of archives.)

The downside is that we need to rebuild everything when we decide to use a new archive type, but we found that much easier to use than the polymorphic archive support.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this older thread.

http://lists.boost.org/boost-users/2005/01/9390.php

Answer (score 1):

This problem drove me insane until I realized that my base class was not polymorphic. In other words, it never used the keyword "virtual" anywhere. Because I didn't need polymorphic behavior.

Here is how I fixed it:

1. I just slapped the keyword "virtual" on some random method in my base class.
2. In my derived class's .cpp file, I added the following:

   ```
   #include <boost/serialization/export.hpp>
   BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT(testnamespace::derivedclass)
   ```

This is all that I had to do.

Answer (score 0):

you can use and unique BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_GUID() for each .cpp
and add it only in the .cpp. not the .h