# C++ Boost deserialization what(): input stream error

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, deserialization

I'm trying to make a serialization of an object and then to deserialize it. Even though it seems that everything I wrote is ok I'm still getting an error during the deserialization.

```
int main(){

MapAttributes mapAtt(MAP_SIZE,MAP_SIZE);

initMapFromImage("map1.png",&mapAtt);


int prevxMax = mapAtt.prevxMax ;
int prevyMax = mapAtt.prevyMax ;
int prevxMin = mapAtt.prevxMin ;
int prevyMin = mapAtt.prevyMin ;


PixelCoords pose = PixelCoords(mapAtt.robotPose.dx, mapAtt.robotPose.dy);
PixelCoords target = PixelCoords( 2048+250, 2048+250 );


PartitionGraphNodes partitionGraph(&mapAtt);
PartitionGraphNodes partitionGraph2(&mapAtt);
partitionGraph.createIncrementalPartition(pose,target);

if (partitionGraph.nodes.size()!=0){
    saveSerializedObject<PartitionGraphNodes(partitionGraph,"partition_graph_marshall");

    std::cout << "size= " << partitionGraph.nodes.size() << "\n";
    restoreSerializedObject<PartitionGraphNodes>(partitionGraph2,"partition_graph_marshall");

}
else{

    std::cout << "RUN FOR YOUR LIVES!!!\n";
}
return 0;
```

This is my code where I'm trying to get my objects serialized and deserialized.

Here is the function for the serialization and the deserialization:

```
template<class T>
void saveSerializedObject(const T &s, const char * filename){
// make an archive
std::ofstream ofs(filename);
boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(ofs);
oa << s;
}


template<class T>
void restoreSerializedObject(T &s, const char * filename)
{
    // open the archive

    std::ifstream ifs(filename);
    if (ifs.good()) {

    std::cout << "Coming!!!\n";
            boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(ifs);
            ia >> s;
    } else {
            // throw an error or something
            assert(false);
    }

 }
```

Finally I have wrote the code for the serialization exactly as the Boost documentation suggests, but I still get an error: an instance of 'boost::archive::archive_exception' what():  input stream error. Can you help me with that?

EDIT:

As it is clear enough, initially I'm trying to serialize an object of class PartitionGraphNodes. So this is how an PartitionGraphNodes object is serialized:

```
#include <boost/serialization/base_object.hpp>
 class PartitionGraphNodes: public NodesVector{

private:
    std::vector<int> targetNeighbors;           //!<Vector holding target neighbors

std::vector<int> robotNeighbors;            //!<Vector holding robot neighbors  
std::vector<PixelCoords> uniformPartition;

public:

PartitionGraphNodes(MapAttributes* mapAttr);    
void createIncrementalPartition(PixelCoords startPos, PixelCoords target);      
int insertNodeInPartition(Node currNode);



template<class Archive>
void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version)
{
    // serialize base class information
    std::cout << "In partition_serial" << "\n";
    ar & boost::serialization::base_object<NodesVector>(*this);
}
};

#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>
class NodesVector{

protected:

    //~ std::vector<Voronode> nodes;

public:

    NodesVector(void){};
    std::vector<Node> nodes;
    MapAttributes* mapAttributes;

    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version)
    {
            std::cout << "In nodesVector_serial" << "\n";
            ar & nodes;
    }

};


#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>
class Node{

public:

PixelCoords p;                      //!< The coordinates of the node
bool visited;                       //!< True if the node has been visited
unsigned int ID;                    //!< The node's ID
int parent;

std::vector<PixelCoords> neigh;     //!< Vector of the neighbors of the node (coords)
std::vector<unsigned int> neighID;  //!< Vector of the neighbors' IDs
std::vector<float> dist;            //!< Vector of the distances of the neighbors

Weight w;                           //!< The node's weight

std::vector<PixelCoords> path;

Node(PixelCoords a) {p=a;}   
Node(PixelCoords a,unsigned int IDt) {p=a; ID=IDt;}
Node(void){}           

void makeNeighbor(Node &a);     


template<class Archive>
void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version)
{
        std::cout << "In nodes_serial" << "\n";
        ar & p;
        ar & visited;
        ar & ID;
        ar & parent;
        ar & neigh;
        ar & neighID;
        ar & dist;
        ar & w;
}


};

#endif
```

Comment: Please, help us to help you - write a minimally complete example reproducing the problem.

Comment: I've made the appropriate edits in my post. I hope it's clear enough now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need 
    BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT();
lines.

See for instance the answers to this question: [Where to put BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT for boost::serialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3396330/where-to-put-boost-class-export-for-boostserialization)